# Using subprocess to control Minecraft servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I run a number of modded Minecraft servers for friends on my PC, I am trying to build a program that makes starting them and sending commands to them much easier.

I launch the servers using a bat file and have been able to get `subprocess` to do that no problem, but I am unsure how to go about adding the functionality of issuing commands to the server via the console.

I've thought of using `stdin.write()` and in the interactive console it works great. The issue is that when I add it to the code it executes the stop command before the server has even started therefore the server never stops. I have tried doing it in a separate function but that didn't work either.

Here is my code so far:

Class file:

```
import subprocess

class Server:
    def __init__(self, server_start_bat, dir):
        self.server_start_bat = server_start_bat
        self.dir =dir


    def start_server(self):
        server = subprocess.Popen(self.server_start_bat, cwd=self.dir, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        server.communicate()


    def stop_server(self):
        server = subprocess.Popen(self.server_start_bat, cwd=self.dir, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        server.stdin.write('stop\n')


    def command(self, command):
        server = subprocess.Popen(self.server_start_bat, cwd=self.dir, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        self.command = command
        server.stdin.write(f'{self.command}\n')
```

Simple GUI I ran it through:

```
from tkinter import *

import Servers

server = Servers.Server('path\\to\\bat\\file\\batfile.bat', 'dir\\to\\run\\command\\in')

main = Tk()
main.title('Server Commander')
server_title = Label(main, text="server, hosted on port ")
server_title.pack()
server_start = Button(main, text='Start', command=server.start_server)
server_start.pack()
server_stop = Button(main, text='Stop', command=server.stop_server)
server_stop.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, I think:

1. `stop_server` and `command` each start a new subprocess, which should only be done in `start_server`.
2. `start_server` uses `server.communicate()` which blocks until the subprocess is done, preventing the program to send any other commands to the server while it is running.

Instead,

- `start_server` should create the subprocess, then store it in a variable which can be accessed by `stop_server` and `command`,
- `server.communicate` should be done in `stop_server`.

`stop_server` is also just a special case of `command`.

```
import subprocess

class Server:
    def __init__(self, server_start_bat, dir):
        self.server_start_bat = server_start_bat
        self.dir = dir

    def start_server(self):
        self.server = subprocess.Popen(self.server_start_bat, cwd=self.dir, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    def stop_server(self):
        self.command('stop')
        self.server.communicate()

    def command(self, command):
        self.server.stdin.write(f'{command}\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That has fixed the main issue I was having